# Django what if the change is applied on database manually

Tags: django, django-models

I have short question. Let's assume in migration file I have some change that was already done manually on database level. Does migration will be applied without throwing an error?

Comment: Is possible, but possible not, so you should *not* alter the database manually. Django does not first inspect the state of the database, that would also make the situation a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

> Does migration will be applied without throwing an error?

**Possibly**, but it is definitely possible that it will trigger errors.

Indeed, migrations alter the database, like adding columns, removing tables, changing database types, etc.

A migration file simply translates to a set of altering statements. Some of these statements can be done carefully, like a `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo`.

But a migration thus does not first checks the database, and then aims to get the database in the state that the migration aims to bring it in. First checking and then trying to counteract certain migrations that already took place could be quite problematic.

As a general rule of thumb, if a database is managed by Django, *don't* alter it manually.

Comment: i see but lets take concrete situation. I go to database and change column type manually. Then I have migration file that have that change also. I do the `makemigration` command. If my understanding is correct `django` will not inspect database which means it will simply trigger the change which is already there and depending on change error may or may not be thrown am i correct? And what about this concrete situation will `django` thrown or not the error?

Comment: @Arie: in this case, likely yes, since changing the type is an idempotent operation.

Comment: So u mean my understanding is generally right and moreover in that particular case no error will be thrown?

Comment: @Arie: no, if the migration file *only* contains such type change. If there are however data migrations for example, then this *can* result into trouble, so it is better *not* to do these.